# ASA5520 7.2 to 8.x upgrade

Tags: security, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

Our customer  wants to upgrade his ASA5520 from 7.2 to 8.x. He has quite a big config and uses lot of features. eg.

a/s failover,
subinterfaces,
~70 VPN tunnels (ssl and ipsec),
bunch of grouped object's,
some policy-maps, 
lot of ACL's,
NAT exemptions etc.....

Does anyone have some best practice Experiences?

Are there a lot differences in the config Syntax to the 8.x ?

sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have problem from 7.2 to 8.x, as the [Cisco documentation says](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/release/notes/asarn82.html#wp315678):
"Therefore, to upgrade from Version 7.0 to Version 8.2, first upgrade from 7.0 to 7.1, then from 7.1 to 7.2, and finally from Version 7.2 to Version 8.2 (8.1 was only available on the ASA 5580)."
When booting the first time, configuration adjustement will be done if needed.

So if you're already in 7.2 it's ok. Just take care that when both device run different OS version at the same time you will lost the failover link. (So you can't upgrade without interrupt)

Comment: Also i would add write your config to a machine (AKA back it up first!) and keep the 7.2 image around so you can fail back if something goes reaaally wrong. You should be able to keep both images on the device. And don't forget to update your ASDM image.